# Problem sending email with Google App Password in my function

Tags: python, mail-server

I'm trying to create a function in Python that enables me to send an email from my email address to that of my intended recipient.

I have set up Google's 2-Step Verification with my Gmail and have set up a Google App Password.

So far, I have looked at examples online, but I don't know why `send_email()` is not working:

```
def send_email():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo() 
    server.login('<my_email_address>', '<google_app_password>')

    subject = 'You've Got Mail!'
    body = 'How are you buddy?'

    message = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    server.sendmail(
        '<my_email_address>',
        '<my_intended_recidpients_email_address>',
        message
    )
    print('Email has been successfully sent')

    server.quit()
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: as for me script may not works if you use  2-Step Verification because you may get code on phone which you may have to use in your code - and it can be problem.

Comment: You might want to replace `subject = 'You've Got Mail!'` with `subject = "You've Got Mail!"`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing 2 lines of code.

After `server.ehlo()`, you need:

```
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
```

`server.starttls()` is necessary since it tells an email server that an email client wants to turn an existing insecure connection into a secure one.

The second `server.ehlo()` after `server.starttls()` is needed because after completing the TLS handshake, the SMTP protocol is reset to its initial state.

Comment: So below `def send_email():`, I need:
  `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)`
 `server.ehlo()`
`server.starttls()`
 `server.ehlo()`
 `server.login('<my_email_address>', '<google_app_password>')`